# rails -h showing the wrong help message inside a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When you are outside of a rails project, and you do rails -h, then the rails help ofthe command rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog should open, but when you are inside a rails app, the help page with explanations for the generate, console, server dbconsole commands etc should open. but for a particular rails 3.0.9 app, even inside the project, the first help message is shown and not the latter one with help for generate, console and other commands. Consequently, i cannot run rails generate migration some_migration in my rails app. what is wrong with my configuration and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If the first one is shown then you're missing the `script/rails` file that Rails depends on to determine if it is inside a Rails application or not. Restore this file and you should be good to go.